# Rtf manipulation in SQL

Tags: sql, firebird, rtf

I have to concatenate (join) two blob fields that contains RTF documents. Is it possible doing this operation in SQL language?

Is it possible embed rtf document into another rtf document (easly)?

Answer (score 0):

Firebird supports BLOB concatenation so yes, you can join two BLOB fields. However, you wouldn't get the desired result as you can't just stuff one rtf file into the end of other and get a valid document. rtf file has a certain structure and you must carefully merge the information in both files to get merged document. This could be done with an UDF (User-defined function) but it is probably easier to do it in the client program.

Comment: Yes, I know that firebird admit blob concatenation, but I would get a valid RTF document!

Comment: UDF function is not a valid solution for me, because I couldn't easily update UDF library (for redistribution problem)

Comment: In client program I found several limitations or problem

Comment: Well, there is no way to do it easily in pure SQL, thats for sure! Perhaps it is best to save into the DB already merged document? ie, why have you merge the rtf in the first place?

Comment: I create dynamically the first document in a store procedure, the second come from a field